# Getting Type Error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write matrix multiplication programme.But I am getting error called 
"Type Error:Int Object is not iterable".This is my code

```
def matmult(m1,m2):
  r1=[]
  r2=[]
  for a in range(len(m2[0])):
    r1.append(0)
  for b in range(len(m1)):
    r2.append(r1)
  for i in range(len(m1)):
    for j in range(len(m2[0])):
      for k in range(len(m2)):
        r2 += m1[i][k]+m2[k][j]
```

I am getting error at last line of code.What could be the cause?

Comment: You're trying to add an integer to a list. Use `r2.append(m1[i][k]+m2[k][j])` instead if you want to append the result of `m1[i][k]+m2[k][j]` to `r2`.

Comment: I did as you told @ZeroPiraeus  but this time it is showing the error as "Type Error: none type object cannot be appended"